# Segmentation Fault on Hello World Program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

I am using VS-Code with g++ as my Compiler.

```
g++ --version 
g++.exe (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I debug it, it shows me "segmentation error" at `std::cout << "Hello World!";`

I have followed all tutorials on official docs, like VS-Code C++ docs, but can't seam to make it work.

[image]

UPDATE:
After trying to figure out the Problem I have found that it only doesn't work when executing it in VS-Code!

Comment: The code is fine, so it has to be a problem with your environment setup.

Comment: A DLL issue. Make sure MSYS2 is the first entry on your PATH, both system-wide and user-specific (`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, substitute `mingw64` for the environment you're using).

Comment: Have done both. The Problem still exists

Comment: Build and test it your code in the mingw64 terminal. If it works there you likely have not solved the `PATH` problem. If it does not work there you could have other issues like an antivirus or a virus problem.

Comment: It works in the terminal!

Comment: Minor point: formally, output is required to be ended with a newline. On real systems these days that doesn't matter, but `std::cout << "Hello World!";` should be `std::cout << "Hello World!\n";`.

Comment: @Lytrix Can you show the contents of your PATH? Both system-wide and user-specific. Did you restart VSC after setting it? Which `g++` are you using? (what directory is it in?) Search in `C:\Windows` (and subdirectories) for `libstdc++-6.dll` and delete it if it's there.

Comment: I had to restart VSC :D thank you very much

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DLL issue. Make sure MSYS2 is the first entry on your PATH, both system-wide and user-specific (C:\msys64\mingw64\bin, substitute mingw64 for the environment you're using). –
HolyBlackCat

Fixed my Issue. I just had to restart VS-Code as well

Comment: Related to the update behavior in environment variables: [https://serverfault.com/questions/8855/how-do-you-add-a-windows-environment-variable-without-rebooting](https://serverfault.com/questions/8855/how-do-you-add-a-windows-environment-variable-without-rebooting)

Comment: Better option: don't put *any* tool and toolchains into the system path and configure tools that need toolchains with the explicit path to them.