# Why does the using of vectors seems to break simple C++ program?

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors

I am playing with some very simple programs to gain familiarity with C++ vectors and seem to be getting some unexpected behaviour. It started by trying to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};

    cout << ("Elements in the vector are:") << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This successfully compiled, but running the executable on the command line did nothing - the cursor just moved to a new line. I thought this might be some weird issue with the loop, but running the below acted as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Given that the vector library is still being loaded in, that discounted some possible error having occurred there. I then compiled and ran the next file which again, did nothing - cursor just moving to a new line:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

   vector<int> v = {12,14,16,18,20};

   cout <<"Goodbye" << endl;
   return 0;

}
```

This suggests to me that the compiler is doing something strange when a vector is defined which corrupts the entire file (given that neither print statements are executed). I am using the g++ version 12.1.0 compiler on a Windows 10 machine. Any insights would be useful - thanks.

Comment: There is no separate "vector library" that needs to be "loaded in". It's part of the core C++ standard library, and is loaded together with the rest of the standard library and is available to use from the very start of the program, as anything else in the standard library (like the output in your second example). There must be something else at play here. For example, if you print the size of the vector, `std::cout << v.size() << '\n';`, what happens then?

Comment: Also please tell us ***exactly*** how you build and run the program. Are you building in the console using the `g++` command directly? Are you using an IDE or editor to build and run the program? What options and settings are you using?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Therefore the problem must be with something other than the shown code. The only given information in the above question is the shown code, so it's not possible to say anything more about it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude your first comment is somewhat confusing - if I remove the vector include at the start of the script, the file won't compile due to vector being undefined in the files scope. Furthermore, if I run ```std::cout << v.size() << '\n';```, I get the same behaviour - nothing being outputted to the command line. As for how I am compiling, I am compiling on the command line via ```g++ .\vector.cpp -o .\vector```

Comment: `#include` is done at compile-time, the code of the header file will practically be copy-pasted into the source that is compiled. Once compiled and linked, there's no activity involving the header file.

Comment: And your problem seems very odd, and will probably be impossible for us to replicate (as seen e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/75cc5h8Gb) and [here](https://godbolt.org/z/oa3dvqv1r)). How did you install the compiler? Where did you get the compiler and its instsallation packages? Is the installation really complete?

Comment: Random guess: your antivirus program is blocking the creation of vector.exe and you are actually seeing the output of an older version. This is corroborated by the "Hello world" print not appearing. Try removing the existing vector and vector.exe files and/or writing to a different filename.

Comment: Virus checker is one possibility. Another is a version incompatibility with, or having no access to, the C++ standard library. But as everyone else has said, there is no problem with the code. Regarding your confusion over the vector library, it's just a terminology issue, `<vector>` is a header file, not a library.

Comment: you may want to check exactly which libraries are loaded when you run the program, my guess is you have several versions of the compiler and it is loading the wrong version.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76657049/2752075

Answer (score -1):

The provided code should provide the expected result according to the standard. There is nothing wrong with the code.

There must be something wrong with one or more of the following:

1. The compiler is buggy (not likely).
2. The compiler has not been installed correctly or the installation process has been corrupted.
3. The compiler is incorrectly invoked.
4. The system is not configured correctly.
5. The compiled program is not correctly executed.

Which of these statements is relevant cannot be determined by us.

One thing you can try is to see if `MSVC` behaves differently as this is the *de facto* standard compiler for Windows.