# Segmentation Fault on std::cout

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, g++, cout, msys2

I have the same problem as described in this question: [Segmentation Fault on Hello World Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76656944/segmentation-fault-on-hello-world-program). I was using this tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw.

```
$ g++ --version
g++.exe (Rev7, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.1.0 
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc. 
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO 
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Hello World runs fine in the cmd and in the MSYS2 UCR64 shell, but VS Code throw a segmentation fault. I have already put C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin to the top of the PATH variables list (both user and system), restart VS Code, but that doesnt't help. Don't know what to do.